# Define template class itself to a type

Tags: c++, templates

I am learning template knowledge and find some template usage like

```
template<typename T> struct myclass
{
...
   typedef myclass type;
...
}
```

From my understanding, I can only use "myclass" with T specified. Like

```
myclass<int> member;
```

Now it defines "myclass" to "type" without specifing the T, so I would like to know in which case "type" will be used.

An example will be really appreciated.

Comment: Inside `myclass` definition, `myclass` is `myclass<T>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside of the body of `myclass<T>`, the identifier `myclass` is a synonym for `myclass<T>`, so the line is equivalent to:

```
typedef myclass<T> type;
```